# why if-else condition is not working while using in react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

writing if-else in jsx while writing react code is not working.

```
<div id={if (condition) { 'msg' }}>Hello World!</div>
```

However using ternary operator works.

```
<div id={condition ? 'msg' : null}>Hello World!</div>
```

why is this happening?

Comment: because `if` isn't an rvalue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSX of

```
<div id={condition ? 'msg' : null}>Hello World!</div>
```

which is *not* valid Javascript by itself, will be compiled into the following ReactJS call:

```
React.createElement(
  'div',                            // Element "tag" name.
  { id: condition ? 'msg' : null }, // Properties object.
  'Hello World!'                    // Element contents.
);
```

which *is* valid Javascript, ready to be interpreted/compiled by your Javascript runtime environment. As you can see, there is no way to jam an `if-else` into that statement, as it cannot be compiled into valid Javascript.

---

You could instead use an [immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and pass the value returned from within:

```
<div id={(function () {
    if (condition) {
        return "msg";
    } else {
        return null;
    }
})()}>Hello World!</div>
```

which will compile into the following valid Javascript:

```
React.createElement(
    "div",
    {
        id: (function () {
            if (condition) {
                return "msg";
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        })()
    },
    "Hello World!"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

if-else statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction.
[React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
// This JSX:
<div id={if (condition) { 'msg' }}>Hello World!</div>

// Is transformed to this JS:
React.createElement("div", {id: if (condition) { 'msg' }}, "Hello World!");
```

So, you see if/else does not fit in this model. Better to use it outside of jsx.
may be in render function.